# write a short speech on each one or ..... every one?

Tags: pronouns, each-every

From a multiple choice question:

> You should prepare a list of topics and write a short speech on ____ one.

The correct one is **each**. But I am wondering why **every** can't be working here?

Comment: Idiomatically, ***each*** would be more *likely* in this exact context. But it's a poor quality test, because there's nothing actually *wrong* with ***every***. Or indeed the emphatic version *...write a short speech on **each and every** one.* Note that an idiomatically acceptable emphatic alternative is ***...on every single one***, but I at least wouldn't endorse ***...on each single one*** here (others may think differently, though).